# DNS request timed out. Server: UnKnown Address: 192.168.1.1

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I  have some problem with my DNS server configuration or my Router i guess.

In the browser, i can't open any pages.
i can't ping www.google.com but i can ping the ipadress.

nslookup www.google.com yelds

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

ipconfig /all yelds:

```
IP Configuration for Windows

   Computer name. . . . . . . . . : Asus-PC
   The main DNS-suffix. . . . . . :
   Node Type. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-routing is enabled. . . . : No
   WINS-proxy enabled. . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-25-D3-06-C6-4C
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes
   Local IPv6-address channel. . . : Fe80:: 3d91: 1dce: a561: d209% 11 (main)
   IPv4-address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101 (primary)
   Subnet mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Rent received. . . . . . . . . . : May 9, 2011 12:06:42
   The lease term expires. . . . . . . . . . : May 9, 2011 14:06:41
   Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP-server. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS-servers. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBios over TCP / IP. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection * 2:

   Media State. . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Isatap. {CFA53C79-5BEB-445C-A626-772598C5F
CA4}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection * 6:

   Media State. . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes
```

any idea what could be the problem?
if i login to my router, two dns entries are set.

Answer (score 1):

Change your router DNS entries to something more reliable.  They're probably pointing to your ISP DNS servers.

[Google DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/): 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

[Open DNS](http://www.opendns.com/): 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220

Alternatively, you could just change the DNS entries on your computer.

Comment: how to change the DNS entries on the computer? you mean going to the TCP/IP settings of the active network connection?

Comment: @Mat Yes, that's correct.  Usually with Windows you also have to set up a static IP in order to change the DNS entries (something I hate and wish MS would fix).  Use 192.168.1.x as your IP, where x is outside your DHCP range, 255.255.255.0 as the subnet mask, and 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS servers are wrong.

Go first into the router's control panel (probably at 192.168.1.1) and ensure that the DNS servers are as communicated by your ISP (or choose among [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) or [DNS Advantage](http://www.dnsadvantage.com/)).

Go into the Properties of the Wireless LAN adapter, then into the Properties of TCP/iPv4 (or/and 6), and select "Obtain an IP address automatically", do the same for the DNS server, then OK.

Comment: Downvote a correct answer without explanation ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't take into consideration that the problem isn't the DNS server settings, but possibly the DNS servers themselves.

Comment: @MaQleod: 3 alternative DNS servers *are* listed.

Comment: Switching servers patches a problem, not fixes it, and doesn't identify it either. Also, ISP DNS servers are best to use for a number of reasons, most important of all being response time.

Comment: @MaQleod: Not always - DNS Advantage is faster than my ISP.

Comment: The only advantage to ISP DNS servers is that they are geographically close.  This does not mean they are fast, and they aren't always accurate.